# How to Calculate elevation from gps altitude in flutter

Tags: flutter, gps, tracking

Hello guys i need help I am working on tracking application in flutter and want to calculate Total elevation gain.I am pulling altitude from location but not able to calculate total elevation gain during trip i am saving all altitude values in list.So basically need a formula which provides total elevation gain during trip.
Pulling elevation like this in flutter

elevation = location.coords.altitude.toString();

Comment: Take elevation and store in a variable on the start of the trip. Then while storing each elevation in the list subtract it with the elevation from the elevation recorded on the start of the trip and then take the average of the list of elevations .

Comment: @AdithyaShetty any code reference or code snipet would be really appriciated!Thanks!

Comment: Yes, why not. But can you confirm that the average of all elevations is what you are aiming to achieve.?

Comment: I am adding an answer for getting the average of elevations wrt to the Start of the trip.

Comment: Hello @AdithyaShetty! Thank you so much for your response.Yes i want Elevation gain like Elevation asscent not elevation descent

Comment: Below code isn't helping you out?

Comment: I am not preety sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220619/discussion-between-adithya-shetty-and-ravish-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

Please Read to understand the code

We are comparing three points of elevations:

Let's take a example where the elevation when the user started is 100m

the three elevations in eg: 700m,1000m,800.
The above three elevation shows that the user made a descend after reaching 1000m. so for the elevation gain is 1000-100m =900m which is the true Elevation gain. Where the subtracted 100m is the elevation recorded at the start of the trip.

---

Now let's consider the next three elevations is 800m,600m,700m this show that after descending to 600m user started the climb again.

so now the true descend would be calculating how much the user descended from the 1000m, therefore true descend would be 1000m-600m =400m

### The comments in the code block explain what each step is doing.

---

```
// This jut stimulates elevations in a small trip
  // instead of this list call the functions whenever you record a elevation.
  // and on the end of the trip call the [onStopTrip] function.
  List<double> listOfDemoElevations = [
    200.0, 300.0,400.0,1000.0,800.0,700.0,600.0,500.0,600.0,800.0,300.0,200.0];
  
  ///This Code Snippet compares Elevation of three points to see if the person has started ascending or is descending.
  /// Then the code only stores the point after which user asecded or descended.
  /// Then Calulates the total Elevation Gain or Elevation Loss.
  
  double elevationGain = 0.0;
  double elevationLoss = 0.0;
  double startTripElevation = 100.0; //Record the StartTripElevation;
  double previousElevation = startTripElevation;
  double beforePreviousElevation = startTripElevation;
  double adjustment =startTripElevation ; // this to get the truw ascend or descend

  
  // This function check the three elevation then adds to elevation gain or loss accordinly with adjustment so true elevation gain or loss is recorded.
  void calculateElevationGainLoss(double currentElevation) {
    if (beforePreviousElevation < previousElevation &&
        previousElevation > currentElevation) {
      elevationGain = elevationGain + (previousElevation - adjustment);
      adjustment = previousElevation;
    } else if (beforePreviousElevation > previousElevation &&
        currentElevation > previousElevation) {
      elevationLoss = elevationLoss + (adjustment - previousElevation);
      adjustment = previousElevation;
    }
    beforePreviousElevation = previousElevation;
    previousElevation = currentElevation;
  }

  /// this function check if the elevation at which the user ended the trip to be added to elevation gain or loss
  void onStopTrip(double currentElevation) {
    if (adjustment > currentElevation) {
      elevationLoss = elevationLoss + (adjustment - currentElevation);
    } else if (adjustment < currentElevation) {
      elevationGain = elevationGain + (currentElevation - adjustment);
    }

    
  }

  listOfDemoElevations.forEach((element) {
    calculateElevationGainLoss(element);
  });

  // Call this function when user hits end trip
  onStopTrip(listOfDemoElevations.last);

  print('Elevation gain=$elevationGain');
  print('Elevation loss=$elevationLoss');
```

---

You can put the whole code inside `void main{}` in dartpad and test: